# std::istringstream: error handling difficulties when reading negative values into unsigned variables

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++14, stringstream, string-parsing

I've been using `std::istringstream` for parsing strings for a long time, and reading valid values was never a problem. However, I have discovered some difficulties and oddities performing operations that should be invalid and detecting failures.

See the code (or [try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/QwCNal)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

    std::istringstream ss("-2147483648");
    uint32_t i = 0;
    try {ss >> i;}
    catch (...) {
       i = -3;
    }

    if (ss.fail())
       i = -3;

    std::cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to read `INT_MIN`, a signed value, into a `uint32_t`. I expect a failure of some sort, indicated by the magic value `-3`. And yet, what I see in the output is `2147483648`. How to properly detect a failure in this situation?

If `i` was `uint64_t`, its value is `18446744071562067968`.

I need this call to fail because I don't need my code silently reading garbage. Can my goal be achieved with `std::stringstream`? I would hate to implement my own parser from scratch, or to wrap the simple `ss >> value;` in a dozen sanity check heuristics.

Comment: Btw, your code is *not* reading garbage as -2147483648 and 2147483648 are in the same equivalence class in Z/2^32, so when using some `uint32_t`, those are indistinguishable.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: agreed, I understand that now. Still, I need this to fail because -<something> is not a valid unsigned value.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Great dupe find.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: how is it a duplicate of the question that has no answers to my question? I specifically stated that I want to avoid hand-written heuristics like checking whether the first character is `-`. The single-handed question closures are getting out of hand, no pun intended.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Sure it does. You've been given  enough pointers and an exact duplicate of what you are trying to achieve. Baum knows his stuff.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It's a dupe because both ask how to check for this with standard streams. The answer to both is "You can't". Which makes sense if you drop the incorrect notion of thinking of 1u as the number 1 and accept it's a shorthand notation for the equivalence class that contains the number 1 instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Does the C++ standard define anything through equivalence classes, though?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes. *"Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer."* 6.9.1/4 in N4659. And that arithmetic is defined through equivalence classes. That's not  a C++ thing, that's a math thing.